# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present Angular CORS (not all the time)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm developing an `Ionic application` on `Angular`. While I querying the PHP server, it reproduces a CORS policy error, but not all the time.

For example, in France, I do not have the error, but when I am in Spain with the same code I have this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '... / API / login' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No' Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'header is present on the requested resource.

This is really strange I have already tried to use:

```
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

Here is the Angular code:

```
login(user: User): Observable<object> {
    return this.http
      .post<{ response_msg: object }>(`${this.url}/login`, user).pipe(map((response) => response), catchError((e: any) => {
        return throwError(e);
      })
      );
  }
```

and here is the PHP code:

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400");

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    }

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem a few hours ago. I think your code looks fine. What exactly the login endpoint should doe?

Also, I write my scenario down it may provide you a solution

So in my case was that it kept saying to me that `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header were presented` but this has only happened when requesting 2 specific endpoints

These two endpoint handling files upload to the backend then the backend sends the file to external storage...

And in my case, the problem was I was trying to connect dead external storage and it killed the whole process and kept saying it has `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header was presented` although it was.

So please double check if everything works fine from the API side (in your login endpoint)

Comment: the connection endpoint must verify the token. Indeed it works because I validate the request from postman but also from some ip. as if the problem came from the accommodation